# How is this correct?

Tags: kinematics, dimensional-analysis

**According to the principal of dimensional homogeneity dimensions of all the terms in an equation must be identical.** This is another way of saying that one can add or subtract similar physical quantities. **Then by that principle velocity=displacement/t is wrong because they are different dimensions**. Please explain how they are correct.

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): Consider to provide a more descriptive title.

Comment: feel free to edit if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that you can only add or subtract similar dimensional quantities. But your velocity equation involves no addition or subtraction. You are free to divide and multiply differing dimensional quantities to get the same total dimension each side of the equation.

Comment: so that is to say that we can get quotient and product of different dimensions. lets say in a hypothetical situations apples and bananas are 2 dimensions. apples+bananas don't make sense but their product and quotient does?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make sense to add apples and bananas together, but apples per banana does.

Answer (score 0):

The standard definition of **dimensional homogeneity** means that the combinations of dimensions assigned to each variable are consistent with both sides of the equation - so velocity has units m/s, displacement/t also has units of m/s.